# C# Proxy Generic Parameter From Generic Input

Tags: c#, generics, proxy

I'm writing some tests, and frequently I find myself having to look up generic parameters to pass explicitly pass along.

```
public class MyService : SecureService<RootEntity>
{
   //Intentionally omitted does not provide information related to question
}

public DepedencyReplaceScope<IContextProvider> CreateMockScope<TRootEntity>
{
    var mockCtx = Mock.Of<IContextProvider>(x => x.WriteContext<TRootEntity> == new FakeContext<TRootEntity>())

    return new DependencyReplaceScope(mockCtx);
}
```

Currently when I'm creating mocks for my test, I have too go into the service and find out what it's root is to pass along.  However, It would be a lot nicer if I could create a scope based on the service.

e.g (pseudo code)

```
public DepedencyReplaceScope<IContextProvider> CreateMockScopeFromService<TService>
    where TService : SecureService<>
    define TRootEntity : TService<()>
{
    return CreateMockScope<TRootEntity>();
}
```

This won't work since I don't think there is a way to define a proxy for the Generic.  Is there a way to create this scope solely from the TService (I don't want to use reflection directly to build it, but I don't mind using a hack with a moq since it abstracts the reflection)

Comment: Can you provide usage example? Would something like `MockScopeProvider.CreateMockScopeFromService<MyService>` suit your needs?

Comment: Yeah, that usage works perfect, my main goal is to avoid looking for the entity type in the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing I was able to come up so far was:

```
public static class MockScopeProvider
{
    public static DepedencyReplaceScope<IContextProvider> CreateMockScopeFromService<U>(SecureService<U> dummy)
    {
         // your logic....
         var mockCtx = Mock.Of<IContextProvider>(x => x.WriteContext<U>() == new FakeContext<U>());

        return new DependencyReplaceScope(mockCtx);

    }
}
```

With usage being like that:

```
MockScopeProvider.CreateMockScopeFromService(default(MyService));
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on the right track,  I'm pretty sure I can do this a bit easier if I create another extension method on top of this, to create a mock of the `SecureContextService` and then pass it into your extension, and hopefully the compiler is smart enough to figure out the rest